# Issue with NameError

Tags: python, backup, nameerror

So I am fairly new with coding in Python and in general and I am trying to write a program that will backup files in a giving folder. However, I continue to get a "NameError: name 'src' is not defined. I see some other questions similar about this error but none have yet to make me understand what I am doing wrong or why I get this error. As far as I understand it I am defining 'src' in the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ERROR:
File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/Lab1.py/Lab5.5.py", line 1, in processing

backup(src, dest)

NameError: name 'src' is not defined

```
def backup(src, dest):
#Checking if src and dest directories exist
    sourceFilePath = input('Enter folder path to be backed up')
    destFilePath = input('Please choose where you want to place the backup')
    #found = true
    for directory in [src, dest]:
        if not isdir(directory):
            print(f'could not find {directory}')
        found = False
    if not found:
        exit(1)
#for each file in src
    for sourceFileName in listdir(src):
    #computing file paths
        sourceFilePath = path.join(src, sourceFileName)
        destFilePath = path.join(dest, sourceFileName)
    #backing up file
    copy2(sourceFilePath, destFilePath)
#entry point
    if __name__=='__main__':

    #validating length of command line arguments
        if len(argv) != 3:
            print(f'Usage: {argv[0]} SRC DEST')
        exit(1)

    #performing backup
    backup(argv[1], argv[2])

    #logging status message
    print('Backup succesful!')
```

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Answer (score 1):

why are you prompting the user for `src` and `dest` path though you already pass them as command args? The issue probably came from the fact you didn't provide the `src` arg while running the script. Things like

```sh
python script.py srcpath dstpath
```